# SublimeText3 - Sublimelinter + phplint "no lint errors"

Tags: php, ubuntu, sublimetext3, sublimelinter, phplint

ive installed sublimelinter and the sublimelinter-phplint plugin in ST3. Phplint is installed and is executed by Sublimelinter (no errors shown, path is configured and working!). If i activate the debug mode within sublimelinter and lint the current view he shows me several lint errors in the console, for example:

`37: ERROR: unknown constant PI
 41: ERROR: unresolved function mai1`

and so on...

However if I execute "Show all errors", he says that there are no lint errors. It just seems that he doenst interprete the phplint return correctly. Are there any further advices what to do now to solve the problem?

Comment: I am having the same problem here. Path configuration seems to work, errors show up in debug mode on console, but not graphically. Could you figure it out? If so, please provide your answer here. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, a whole pc restart solved the problem. I have never figured out what the real problem was. I am sorry and wish u good luck.